# how to send message in WhatApp by pywhatkit

Tags: python, whatsapp

I wanna to send the same message to multiple contacts by WhatsApp?and the contacts before ever sent messages to  me, so it's not spam.our code as below:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import csv
from time import sleep
import pywhatkit
import pandas as pd 
#the contat list as below
phones=pd.read_csv("WhatsApp All Contacts.csv")['Phone 1 - Value'].tolist()
#send messages in a random time& minutes
for phone in phones[1:30]:
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(phone,'hello, how are you?',random.randint(15,20),random.randrange(1,60,5))
            
print('finish')
```

the for loop  runs only once using the above code, cause of the time constructor. the time is random, if the setting time is younger in the next loop than the first loop,the script will  stop.
so now i wanna the time is a little older in the next loop than before,anyone can help to tell me how to write the code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one way arround this problem is to start the second parameter from where the first parameter is. You could just start from the number generated for the first paramter instead of starting from 1.
For example like this:

```
for phone in phones[1:30]:
base=random.randint(15,20)
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(phone,'hello, how are you?',base,(random.randrange(base,60,5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use random and use datetime. This way it will not be random and everything will be sequential.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

....

start = datetime.today().replace(hour=15, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
for i, phone in enumerate(phones[1:30]):
    scheduled_time = start + i * timedelta(minutes=5)
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(phone,'hello, how are you?',scheduled_time.hour,scheduled_time.minute)
```

If you really want to add some random part you can and some additional minutes as long as they are not larger than 5. You just need to change the scheduled time like this.

```
scheduled_time = start + i * timedelta(minutes=5) + timedelta(minutes=random.randint(0,5))
```